# variables int m_height; int m_weight; are zero

Tags: c#

So i just started with C#. I thought i would write a little BMI calculator. 
My Problem: both variables int m_height; int m_weight; are zero. Am i supposed to initialize them differently? If so, how? Am i missing something else?

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    int m_height; 
    int m_weight;

    public int Height
    {
        get { return m_height; }
        set { this.m_height = Convert.ToInt32(txtHeight.Text); } 
    }

    public int Weight
    {
        get { return m_height;  }
        set { this.m_weight = Convert.ToInt32(txtWeight.Text);  }
    }

    private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int result = m_weight  / ((int)Math.Pow(m_height, 2));
        txOutput.Text = result.ToString();
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="testApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:testApp"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Name="txtHeight" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="101,129,0,0"/>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Name="txtWeight" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="362,129,0,0" />
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" Name="txOutput" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="232,318,0,0" />
        <Button Content="Sumbit" Name="btnSubmit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="256,223,0,0" Click="btnSubmit_Click" />
        <Label Content="Your Height:&#xD;&#xA;" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="3.089,2.829" Margin="101,99,0,0" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Your Weight:&#xA;Your Weight" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="3.089,2.829" Margin="362,99,0,0" Width="120" Height="24"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: What value do you expect them to be? could you provide the front end code?

Comment: The value is determined by a TextBox. e.g when i enter 180 the value isnt 180

Comment: @tea_baggins can you provide the xaml for the textbox? without knowing the binding it is hard to answer your question.

Comment: `set` takes a *value* (e.g. `Height = 3;` => `Height.set(3)`). Where do you do that?

Comment: Looks like you want to use binding in order to update the values as the text is input. Alternatively, you can create an "OnFocusLost" event to manually update the variables when the textboxes lose focus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're doing here

```
public int Height
{
    get { return m_height; }
    set { this.m_height = Convert.ToInt32(txtHeight.Text); } 
}
```

doesn't do what you think it does. The code in `set` would be executed if you wrote something like `Height = 13;` But in that case, the value (`13`) would be ignored and instead it would be set to the value in your `txtHeight` textbox.

Instead you'll want something like

```
public int Height
{
    get { return Convert.ToInt32(txtHeight.Text); }
}
```

This is basically a readonly property (note that you don't need the field `m_height` if you implement it like this).
This will always return the text in `txtHeight` converted to an `int`. Note that you'll have to add error handling here for the case that the text is not a valid number (or empty).

You can read more about properties on [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties)